# vuejs directive based on variable

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to dynamically assign a directive? I would like to assign success or error based on a variable named type. I currently do this (Which I would like to replace):

```
v-snackbar(v-if="type === 'success'", success, timeout=3000, bottom=true, right=true, v-model='snackbar') {{ snackbarText }}
    v-btn(flat, @click.native="snackbar = false")
        v-icon close
v-snackbar(v-if="type === 'error'", error, timeout=3000, bottom=true, right=true, v-model='snackbar') {{ snackbarText }}
    v-btn(flat, @click.native="snackbar = false")
        v-icon close
```

Comment: Do you mean dynamically assign a property? That's what your example seems to do

Comment: I would like to replace (v-if="type === 'success'", success) with just type

Answer (score 1):

error and success are not directives, they are props on the v-snackbar component.

You can bind to the error and success props directly with a boolean expression or a variable.

```
v-snackbar(:error="type === 'error'", :success="type === 'success'", timeout='3000', bottom='bottom', right='right', v-model='snackbar')
    | {{ snackbarText }}
    v-btn(flat='flat', @click.native='snackbar = false')
      v-icon close
```

Here it is in html for those who get confused by the pug syntax.

```
<v-snackbar :error="type === 'error'" :success="type === 'success'" timeout="3000" bottom="bottom" right="right" v-model="snackbar">{{ snackbarText }}
  <v-btn flat="flat" @click.native="snackbar = false">
    <v-icon>close</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-snackbar>
```

Take a look at Example 2 on the vuetifyjs website for a more complete example.
https://vuetifyjs.com/components/snackbars